# Is that worth it to find a designer for creating a WordPress theme for selling on ThemeForest?

Tags: themes

I am skilled enough in WordPress and frontend development - CSS3/HTML5/JS. But I am not sure I can get approved quickly by ThemeForest team from design point of view. So I am wondering, do you think it's worth it to find some great designer, pay for PSD design that is done right way, turn it into HTML then into WordPress theme and try to publish on ThemeForest? What could you advise to do in my situation?
Thanks!

Comment: Before you do that, you should ask Hansel and Gretel what happened when they went into the Forest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with that.

Generally speaking, designers and developers work together and it appears that on ThemeForest there are teams of people working to deliver these themes. There isn't really anything wrong with hiring or using a design consultant to design the theme if you are confident you can develop it to a high standard (e.g. that it is well-documented; simple to customise; compatible with current and popular plugins; and finally, that you are willing to update it frequently to provide bug fixes and provide support).

The only thing I'd be slightly concerned about is that you say you're good at "front-end" development. Are you familiar with PHP? All customisation on WP involves a consolidated knowledge of PHP. Hope this helps.